# Copy Reactor Context to MDC in the case of TimeoutMainSubscriber

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, mdc

I have been following the code at https://github.com/archie-swif/webflux-mdc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/webfluxmdc/MdcContextLifter.java to put data from Reactor Context to MDC using hooks.

The solution works perfectly in most of the cases except for when `Mono` is timing out and `TimeoutMainSubscriber` is in use.

Below is the small test that I used.

```
Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono.just(1)
            .doOnEach(logger.addToContext(i -> ImmutableMap.of("index", i)))
            .flatMap(___ -> Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            }))
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000), Schedulers.parallel())
            .doOnEach(logger.info("testMDCLogging"))
            .doOnError(logger.error("testMDCErrorLogging"))
            .subscriberContext(logger.initContext());
```

When verifying the propagation of Context through MDC lifters, `onNext()` `onError()` and `onComplete()` are not called in `TimeoutMainSubscriber` (where the Context is copied over to MDC), only `currentContext()` is called.

How do I propagate the Context and copy over to MDC to be used in `doOnError` and `doOnEach` in the case of `Mono` timeout? I don't want to move the copy to `currentContext()` because this method is called several times and it is not an optimal solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try overriding `onError` method in MdcContextLifter class?

```
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        copyToMdc(coreSubscriber.currentContext()); // similar to onNext()
        coreSubscriber.onError(t);
    }
```

Comment: No because it won't work. onNext(), onError() and onComplete() are not called in TimeoutMainSubscriber when Mono is Timeout. Only currentContext() is called.

Comment: @marcterenzi they are not called because the upstream times out. However, the error is propagated downstream. So if you do what Nipuna suggests, then it should work as expected.